# How can I get 7,800 war assets in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I want to get the ending where Shep breathes. But getting to 7,800+ war assets is proving to be extremely difficult!

I know that I should probably make peace between the Quarians and Geth, but that's difficult too

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would assume you are asking from the Legendary edition? Because back in the original version there was a multiplayer that I think was stripped from the Legendary edition. That multiplayer was needed to get the best ending.

Comment: @Fredy31: Do you have a source for that? I got the best ending way back when, and definitely never played multiplayer.

Comment: https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/War_Assets As such, the highest obtainable War Assets score is approximately 7500. If the multiplayer mode is not played, the player will only be able to acquire ~3750 EMS, which is less than the ~4000 EMS necessary to experience all possible endings. Downloadable content for Mass Effect 3 significantly affects the War Assets system. Mass Effect 3: Extended Cut lowers the EMS required to achieve all possible endings from ~4000 to 3100.

Comment: I played ME3 on release so I guess my memory was before the DLC made it possible to hit the best ending without playing the Multiplayer.

Comment: Here is a full checklist of every scenario and how it must be completed for the best effect on the war assets. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pbVWgC1aPxc3YyelltVmI3UVE/view?resourcekey=0-KPBNSazykgtwXF2TrY-cGg I don't really know where to upload this file for preservation sake, but its been available for 4 years and is still here.

Answer (score 1):

For Legendary Edition, my Paragon run got 8000+, and Renegade got 7800+ (and "best" Destroy), by doing almost everything including Omega and Leviathan. Saved Wrex, made peace between Quarians and Geth. Renegade lost Eve and had [fake queen](/questions/56603). Need to do the side quests and search everywhere for Assets: the non-quest ones total more than a few hundred.

On my third run, leaning toward Synthesis (which the online guides are less clear about for LE) but I skipped the two DLC and some searches. Before Cerberus HQ I had 6389. Then added 110 for the Reaper Brain totalling 6499. I would have been annoyed if I was off by one. But I got it.

(For the original release, you would increase your Readiness percentage from 50% to 100% by playing Multiplayer OR a free iOS app. Later that app was replaced with a web app. There was also a separate mobile game for a few years.)